# Dev Demon Forum Subscribe

Tags: devdemon

I have Forum Subscribe installed.

If I log in as a member and click subscribe it just goes to an ACT URL and then if I go back it says I am subscribed, however if I then login to another account and post into the forum that I subscribed to the member does not get a notification?

Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Comment: Have you checked if any of your emails are coming through? Test in communicate?

Comment: Hi are you reffering to other emails? Everything else works fine, just not the forum subscribe for some reason?